# $FM$ is tangent to $\omega$

Tags: geometry

Let $\omega$ be a circle and $A, B, C, D\in \omega$ s.t.  $AB||CD$ and $AD\cap BC=\{F\}$, $AC\cap  BD=\{E\}$, Let $M,N\in \omega$ s.t. $MN||AB||CD$,  $E\in MN$.
Show that $FM$ is tangent to $\omega$.[image]

I tried to prove it with the power of point $F$ relative to $\omega$.

Answer (score -1):

Comment: Join F to center of circle O and extend it to meet the circle $\omega$ at H. FO intersect $\omega$ at G. If $FG=r_{\omega}$ due to statement we have to have:

$FM^2=FG\times FH=r\times 3r=3r^2$

Also if FM is tangent to $\omega$ then MO must be perpendicular to MF, in this case in right angle triangle FMO we have:

$FM^2=FO^2-MO^2=(2r)^2-r^2=3r^2$

Note that quadrilateral ABCD is isosceles trapezoid.

Update: This is particular case. Other configuration also meet the conditions of statement. To show this draw a circle it's diameter is FO. You have to show this circle passes points M and N, that is MN is common chord of two circles. For this extend MN from for example N. Take an arbitrary point like P on it and draw tangents to circles from P. If you prove these tangents are equal, then MN is radical axis of two circles(see Wiki for radical axis) and MN is common chord; that results in $\angle FMO=90^o$ and FM is tangent to $\omega$

Comment: I made a GeoGebra model which indicates that $FG=r$ is not a necessary condition.